# Showing demand for my research - referencing forums

Tags: citations, quotation

I want to show that there is demand for my research.

There are lots of comments on the internet, e.g. on forums, from people seeking the answers my research will provide.

How do I quote these comments in my paper correctly?

Comment: If you are trying to justify your research for a funding committee, for example, they are unlikely to be persuaded by some comments on the internet. Are you able to at least cite a literature review that highlighted a gap in knowledge, or some data about how many people are affected by the underlying problem or similar?

Comment: I'm not trying to get funding.

Comment: A comment in a forum tells me that a random internet guy doesn't know the solution. A published literature review tells me that a leading expert doesn't know the solution (and a couple of referees agree with him).

Comment: I can't find a suitable literature review.

Comment: Where have you researched?  Google Scholar etc?

Comment: Yes Google Scholar.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in comments, I can't imagine forum comments being useful for proving anything much (unless you have literally thousands of comments all asking the same thing). Even if 50 people have asked, that's not really proving it's in demand.

If it's of a big enough magnitude, I'd suggest some sort of keyword analysis across forums. That or try to do some proper polls with a big enough sample size.

Anything else just shows 'someone on the internet was wondering this too'